# How to avoid content reflow with Ant Design's responsive Sider

Tags: reactjs, antd

I expect the responsive Sider component to expand without causing the reflow of elements in Content component, which is not the case with my render method as below.

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

// ...skipped

render() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Sider
        breakpoint="sm"
        collapsedWidth="0"
        onCollapse={(collapsed, type) => { console.log(collapsed, type); }}
        style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
      >
        <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" selectedKeys={['1']}>
          <Menu.Item key="1">
            <Icon type="user" />
            <span className="nav-text">nav 1</span>
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="2">
            <Icon type="video-camera" />
            <span className="nav-text">nav 2</span>
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </Sider>
      <Layout>
        <Content style={{ margin: '10px', padding: "15px" }}>
          <ListOfData />
        </Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

What I want to achieve is the Sider effect applied in [Ant Design's documentations site](https://ant.design/components/layout/) when it is visited with a mobile view port, which visually pushed the page content to the right.

I took a look at the site mentioned above with react inspection tool, but I can't tell which official component is used to do that. However, I am guessing it mixed the Drawer component in Ant Design Mobile, because the drawer class was there.

Is it possible to use only the components from Ant Design to achieve that?

What I want 
[image: What I want to achieve]

My Collapsed Sider

[image: My Collapsed Sider]

My Expanded Sider

[image: My Expanded Sider]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lib rc-drawer-menu

```
<Drawer width="240px">
      <Menu
        style={{ width: 240, height: '200%' }}
        defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
        defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
        mode="inline"
      >
        <SubMenu
          key="sub1"
          title={<span><Icon type="mail" /><span>Navigation One</span></span>}
        >
          <MenuItemGroup key="g1" title="Item 1">
            <Menu.Item key="1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
          </MenuItemGroup>
          <MenuItemGroup key="g2" title="Item 2">
            <Menu.Item key="3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
          </MenuItemGroup>
        </SubMenu>
        <SubMenu
          key="sub2"
          title={<span><Icon type="appstore" /><span>Navigation Two</span></span>}
        >
          <Menu.Item key="5">Option 5</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="6">Option 6</Menu.Item>
          <SubMenu key="sub3" title="Submenu">
            <Menu.Item key="7">Option 7</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="8">Option 8</Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>
        </SubMenu>
        <SubMenu
          key="sub4"
          title={<span><Icon type="setting" /><span>Navigation Three</span></span>}
        >
          <Menu.Item key="9">Option 9</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="10">Option 10</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="11">Option 11</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="12">Option 12</Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
      </Menu>
    </Drawer>
    <div
      style={{
        width: '100%', height: 667, background: '#fff000',
        color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: '667px',
      }}
    >
      内容区块
    </div>
```

I believe using antd pro will sort with such as it comes out of the box. With many more components for a standard application
You can preview some more andt components here for your case have a look at SLIDER menu.

https://preview.pro.ant.design/#/

Comment: [rc-drawer-menu](https://react-component.github.io/drawer-menu/) does what I want, thanks very much for the information

Answer (score 3):

OK. We are a year further.
When I was playing with the CodePen which is linked on https://ant.design/components/layout/ and adding:

```
<Sider
  ..
  style={{position: "absolute", height: "100vh"}}
  ..
```

it simply worked for me..